# How to get the range of Fiscal years from FiscalYearSettings based on Current FIscal Year Dynamically?

Tags: apex, soql, date

I am trying to fetch the Fiscal Year Setting Records using SOQL for the fiscal years based on current fiscal year. I need few records before the current fiscal year and a few records after the current fiscal year dynamically.

I tried the below but that ain't working :

```
SELECT Id, PeriodId, StartDate, EndDate, Name FROM FiscalYearSettings WHERE StartDate > LAST_N_FISCAL_YEARS:5 AND EndDate < NEXT_N_FISCAL_​YEARS:3
```

I think I am using the NEXT_N_FISCAL_YEARS and LAST_N_FISCAL_YEARS wrong.

Comment: What is the error you are facing. In your query there is not AND/OR operator in two conditions. [SELECT Id, PeriodId, StartDate, EndDate, Name FROM FiscalYearSettings WHERE StartDate >= LAST_N_FISCAL_YEARS:2 AND StartDate <= NEXT_N_FISCAL_YEARS:1  Order By StartDate ASC] This query will provide you last two fiscal years, current fiscal year and one future fiscal year.

Comment: @Amit That worked. Your query worked. Apparently, I can use the LAST_N_FISCAL_YEARS and NEXT_N_FISCAL_YEARS on a single variable itself and not 2 variable like I also used the EndDate. Thanks. PS: I did update the question and added the AND that was missing.

Comment: Adding this as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This SOQL query will provide you last two fiscal years, current fiscal year and one future fiscal year.

```
[SELECT Id, PeriodId, StartDate, EndDate, Name FROM FiscalYearSettings WHERE StartDate >= LAST_N_FISCAL_YEARS:2 AND StartDate <= NEXT_N_FISCAL_YEARS:1 Order By StartDate ASC]
```